# Adjust Vim colorscheme for ruby hash syntax key: :val

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, color-scheme

Is there a way to have the value symbol or key symbol in a key-value pair highlighted differently?

something like:

ruby: **:has_nice_hash**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the colour of a specific syntax token in Vim you have to know its idName. You can place the cursor on the token and then on the command line type the following command:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

In the case of the ruby hash you'll get `rubySymbol`. Now with this information you can do something like:

```
:hi rubySymbol guifg=red
```

Of course you'll have to tweak the colors based on your needs. See [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27highlight%27) for further information.

Comment: But as per my example aren't ruby: and :has_nice_hash both symbols? I'd want them to be styled differently...

Comment: I think you can't have it. See this https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/syntax/ruby.vim but I'm fairly sure.